# Math Competition (Math Olympiad)

Tags: soft-question

In the future, I will take part in a Maths Olympiad
Here's my question:

This questions is mainly regarding The Math **Theory** involved. (not mainly problem solving). What basic concepts ( **Mathematics Theory**) do I need to study for a Maths Olympiad, also what mathematical t**echniques will I have to master?**

What are the best resources for **foundation/ simple** **mathematical techniques** (e.g. piegonhole principle, factorisation, similar triangle..etc) which are not only a must for mathematical olympiads but also for problem solving and general.

These resources could include: Books, website, Single Pdf docucments..etc.
I want to broaden my problem solving **technique-knowledge** (e.g methods of solving problems, for diffrent topics i.e. Algebra, Combinatorics, Number Theory.. etc.)
so that when I am faced with a diffcult problem i have a lot of approaches to take and don't run out of ideas.

Comment: You should check out aops

Answer (score 0):

There are lotsw of books, you can search it out on Google.
Like : Polya's How to Solve it, Challenging Mathematical Problems With Elementary Solutions (Volume I & II, Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory) - A. M. Yaglom, I. M. Yaglom. etc.

http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books
http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=mbb%7Ctekstkut