# What are some good problem solving techniques for Math Olympiad style tests?

Tags: contest-math, problem-solving

I am taking part in a Math Olympiad style test at my school in a few weeks. This test is mainly problem solving based and tests you on topics such as counting techniques, algebra, geometry as well as some miscellaneous topics.

So, I was wondering whether there are any key problem solving tactics to help me solve the questions while at the same time, increasing my efficiency.

I understand that people have asked a question like this before, however, I am asking for some specific techniques to support me problem solving.

Thank you :)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of at least the following question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112209/math-competition-math-olympiad, but possibly also of this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443117/preparing-for-mathematics-olympiad

Comment: I can see that they are a bit similar however, I am asking for some specific techniques not help in general for preparation.

Comment: The first question I mentioned also asks for specific techniques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this book is helpful for finding good strategies:

[Arthur Engel - Problem-Solving Strategies](http://micheleandreoli.org/public/Didattica/olimat/Libri/Engel_A._Problem-solving_strategies_for_math_olympiads__1998.pdf)

Comment: Do you know of anything less complicated?

Comment: @anonymous The book is long, but quite simple and pedagogical, almost a juwel. What do you think would be more suitable for you?

Comment: Something that is aimed more at students in middle school.

Comment: @anonymous I do not really think that it is possible to find something like this... http://world.mathigon.org/ is certainly aimed to students in middle school, and is very pedagogical, but it is not about problem solving strictly, although some ideas may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for the support.